# ImageViews aren't aligned vertically when using padding

Tags: android, padding

Im trying to get two ImageViews side by side with a gap around the image. Ive been using Padding, Margin etc and all have had the same effect (See Image Below)

[image: One image is shifted upwards]

as you can see the image on the right is shifted upwards, how do i stop this?

Here's the layout file im using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Top Row -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/tab_headlines"
            android:src="@drawable/headlines"
            android:layout_margin="5sp"
            />
        <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/tab_headlines"
            android:src="@drawable/headlines"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

I am going to be using more rows of images hence the extra LinearLayout

Comment: using `android:layout_weight="1"` for both ImageViews will fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `layout_weight` to divide your layout equally. Try the following code:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Top Row -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/tab_headlines"
            android:src="@drawable/headlines" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/tab_headlines"
            android:src="@drawable/headlines" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Also, never use `sp` for specifying layout dimensions. Use `dp` instead.

Answer (score 1):

**To fix Vertical alignment :**

Use `android:layout_height="match_parent"` in your `ImageView`

by  using `android:layout_height="match_parent"` inside `ImageView` it will be matched to its parent your `LinearLayout` which is `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

**Now Question arises why the height will be same for both `ImageViews`** ?

Reason your parent `LinearLayout's Height` will be `automatically chosen from ImageView` `Whose height is greater` because of `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in your `LinearLayout` !

and by using `android:layout_height="match_parent"` you will be using `same height for ImageView` whose height is smaller !

---

**To Fix Horizontal alignment :**

use `android:layout_weight="equal weight value for btoh"`

change your code to

```
   <ImageView 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/tab_headlines"
        android:src="@drawable/headlines"
        android:layout_margin="5sp"
        />
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/tab_headlines"
        android:src="@drawable/headlines"
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

You have given layout_margin for left side image and didn't give for the right side image.That's where the issue lies. If you want only two images in a row and if the image size is same for the both then you can make use of layout_weight attribute and give padding for space in between them.
so,try this. It will work.

```
    <!-- Top Row -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:contentDescription="@string/tab_headlines"
            android:src="@drawable/headlines"
            android:padding="3dp"
            />
        <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:contentDescription="@string/tab_headlines"
            android:src="@drawable/headlines"
           android:padding="3dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```